# Excel 2010 Formula Bar - autofit?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

In Excel 2003, the formula bar would autofit the height of the active cell.  In Excel 2010, this doesn't happen.  Is there a way to revert the behavior to the Excel 2003 functionality without trying to create it via a VBA solution?

NOTE:  I know there are multiple options for adjusting the height of the formula bar in Excel 2010 (e.g. drag the divder, Ctrl+Shift+u, etc), so I'm not looking for those.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is no.

A [discussion over at the Microsoft Community](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2007-excel/how-do-you-get-the-formula-bar-to-auto-size-with/7c03659c-8d5e-47bd-99a7-8e09f7e23cc1?msgId=e46f417b-4407-46e7-8704-3e98894980f4) indicates that you've pretty much listed the options: VBA, drag the divider, and click the chevron/Ctrl+Shift+U.

I agree with one poster on that thread:

> The formula bar does not auto-size according to the value or formula
>   within the current cell and this behavior is by design. If it did, the
>   screen would be constantly flashing if someone was using one of the
>   arrow keys or Tab to move around the worksheet, reducing and expanding
>   the displayed area of the active worksheet while conversely expanding
>   and contracting the number of lines in the formula bar.

I do want to also point out the thoughts of another poster in that thread:

> Did you know you can hide the ribbon?  If you double click on the
>   active tab in the ribbon, the ribbon is hidden.  When you need a
>   control, you can click on a tab and it comes back.  It now behaves
>   similarly to the old Menus in Office 2003. So with the ribbon hidden,
>   you'll have the extra screen space available to set your formula bar
>   to multiple rows.  3 rows will be the same hieght as the ribbon.